# How to split up the_title and insert a span tag

Tags: get-the-title

My titles, site wide, will follow this theme all within a h1 tag:

Main title heading / Sub-title text

I'm trying to wrap a span tag around all text after and including the '/' so my markup will look like this:

```
<h1>Main title heading <span>/ Sub-title text</span></h1>
```

How do I accomplish this? I'm not great with PHP but I've tried playing with explode but can't get the end result all I end up doing is hiding everything after the '/'

**EDIT:**
Code removed & Pastebin created, this is my whole page for index.php: http://pastebin.com/0T9mt7Fu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its best if you just use **custom field** type to create a sub title...
That way you leave the title un-touched and just add a field where
you can insert a value like so (calling field sub title):

[image]

---

Then you can fetch your subtitle easily:

```
<?php
$sub_title=get_post_meta($post->ID,'subtitle',true);
if($sub_title != '') {
echo '<h1>'. the_title() .'<span>'. $sub_title .'</span></h1>';
} else {
echo '<h1>'. the_title() .'</h1>';
}
?>
```

.
i hope this a suitable solution for you... i use it on occasions

Cheers, Sagive

---

**HOW TO:**

Replace (i hope it looks the same in your theme) with the code above..:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: +1. Two suggestions: 1) Use a fail-safe approach, and only output `<span> . $sub_title . '</span>'` if `$subtitle` is set; and 2) Use the `the_title` filter to modify `the_title()`, rather than having this code directly in the template.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do I put that code in my template file in the place where I want the_title to appear?

Comment: chip is right ofcourse.. edited my code - thanks chip :) - @evan see my "HOW TO" in my answer..

Comment: I've been trying to implement this code but for some reason the_title isn't registering and is being displayed outside of the <h1> tag. So my code looks like Page title<h1></h1> or Page title <h1><span>/ subtitle</span></h1>. Odd. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure... can you paste in you question the code you are trying to change? would gladly try to help

Comment: Here you go... http://pastebin.com/uTx4sEUh

Comment: Dont forget to use the custom field in order to activate the "sub title" other wise you would only get the title..

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news but I've copied your code directly but it still replicates the same issue. The actual title still gets displayed out of all tags. I don't get it, could it be another part of my page that's breaking it? Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/0T9mt7Fu

Comment: try replacing "the_title()" with "get_the_title()"... did that help?

Comment: Ah yes, thats fixed it! Brilliant thanks for your persistence!

Comment: My pleasure mate - glad you got it all to work :)

Comment: This way is not the best, generate not relevant data and change you the theme, then was not used the data and leave only in the database. Also it is not fine to add the content via UI, is an extra field and not important. It is possible to realized the solution via filter hooks or add a meta box, there have the point, that is easier to add the content for all autors.

Answer (score 6):

This comes a bit late, but I don’t know where else it would make sense. I had a similar problem and created a solution.

As [toscho has pointed out](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45589/how-to-split-up-the-title-and-insert-a-span-tag#comment58166_45604), the_title is used in nav menus, too. He has created a [filter to switch the title filter on/off for nav menus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/how-to-apply-a-class-to-the-second-word-in-menu-list-item/44972#44972)—which I personally think is Einsteinesque. (Thanks a bunch!)

So I’ve just modified his filter a little to make it work here. Then added the actual filtering function. Wherever you use space-pipe-space (" | ") in a post title field, the part after it gets wrapped up in a `<span>` tag (including the slash the original post author asked for).

```
/**
 * Append a sub-heading to WordPress post titles
 */

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'gp121028_title_filter_switch' );
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'gp121028_title_filter_switch' );
/**
 * Switch title filter off when menu class starts and on when it ends.
 *
 * @param  mixed $input Array or string, we just pass it through.
 * @return mixed
 */
function gp121028_title_filter_switch( $input ) {
    $func = 'wp_nav_menu_args' == current_filter() ? 'remove_filter' : 'add_filter';
    $func( 'the_title', 'gp121028_filter_title' );
    return $input;
}

/**
 * The actual filter function for the_title()
 */
function gp121028_filter_title( $title ) {
    $substrings = explode( ' | ', $title );
    $title = ( ! empty( $substrings[0] ) ) ? $substrings[0] . '<span>/' . $substrings[1] . '</span>' : $title;
    return $title;
}
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: thats gr8 @glueckpress :) - just keep in mind that the sub title as the title iteself might influence the way google defines that page... nevertheless - gr8 solution. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer @Sagive SEO gave seems like the best approach from a semantic perspective. But if you prefer to keep both "titles" in the title field, a simple explode should work for you.

Try something like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse45589_split_title', 10, 2 );

function wpse45589_split_title( $title, $post_id = null ) {
    if ( !$post_id ) 
        return $title;
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'page' )
        return $title;
    $parts = explode( '/', $title, 2 );
    $title_to_return = $parts[0];
    if ( !empty( $parts[1] ) )
        $title_to_return .= '<span>/'.$parts[1].'</span>';
    return $title_to_return;
}
```

*ETA: following @toscho's suggestion below, I added a couple lines to check the post type before filtering the title. This function should now only add the `<span>`'s to the title on pages, not in nav menus, etc.*

Comment: This would be my preferred option to be honest but where do I add this code? Does this go into the template file itself or within functions.php? If its functions.php do I have to call anything within my template to make it work?

Comment: This is a filter, the best place for it would be your functions.php, but if you only wanted to apply it to one template file, it could go at the top of that file as well.

Once you've added this code, any template file that uses the functions `the_title()` or `get_the_title()` will have this span wrapped around the second part of the title.

Comment: Unfortunately, this matches [titles in nav menus too](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44972/73). You have to check if you are on a real post title first.

Comment: @toscho - Huh. You're right, I didn't even stop to think that wp_nav_menu was using that same filter. I'll update my answer for posterity.