# insert element inside wp menu list item

Tags: menus

I am not sure if it is clear from the title what I want to achieve here so let me try to clarify this.

I wanna make use of Wordpress's menu system and need to adjust it to my needs, which means that I need it to go **from here**:

```
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
etc.
</ul>
```

**to here**:

```
<ul>
<li><div>1(dynamic-content)</div>item1</li>
<li><div>2(dynamic-content)</div>item2</li>
etc.
</ul>
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?? Just need some quick directions to go there and do it myself without losing too much time finding appropriate solution.

Is it the `wp_nav_menu()` or `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` that I should be researching? Short sample would be appreciated as well if it's not too much to ask.
And another thing.. I would appreciate tip on how to generate number inside that inserted `div` that represents menu item's order apperance: 1,2,3,etc. Is there a way to pick up this from Wordpress's core?

Thank you so much. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know exactly the answer, but if you make a search in google about "wordpress menu walker" you will find a solution.

Comment: I usually achieve this using a Walker menu + using the "description" field in the native WP menu so admins can add in that extra text themselves without me having to do anything programatic. :) Here's an article on how to do that: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

Comment: @Michelle: Thanks Michelle, I came across that article as well but didn't find time to take a look. Now that I got encouragement from you I'll check it out for sure. Sounds like an elegant solution. But then again, description field is static and I need to increment variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description/14039#14039) or just [filter the menu title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/how-to-apply-a-class-to-the-second-word-in-menu-list-item/44972#44972). It depends on the position you need for your extra content: Should it appear before or inside the link?

### Example with a walker

*Update: Actually, this cannot work: the parent function creates the `<li`, so you have to copy and adjust the whole parent function.*

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array (
        'walker' => new WPSE_45647_Walker
    )
);

class WPSE_45647_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args )
    {
        $output .= $this->custom_content( $item );
        parent::start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Create your extra content here.
     * @return string
     */
    protected function custom_content( $item )
    {
        // inspect the item and return your 
        // custom content as a string
    }
}
```

### Example with a filter

More hackish, but maybe easier to understand: Grab the `<li>` and replace `<a` with `$custom <a`

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse_45647_add_custom_content', 10, 2 ); 
function wpse_45647_add_custom_content( $item_output, $item )
{
    static $counter = 0; 
    // You may inspect $item and do something more creative here.
    $custom = ++$counter . ' Hello World!'; 
    return str_replace( '<a ', $custom . '<a ', $item_output );
}
```

Comment: before. Thanks for the tip man. if it's not too much to come up with an example I would appreciate it.

Comment: @daniel.tosaba I've added a sample Walker. **Not tested.** Sorry, I don’t have much time. But it should give you a direction. :)

Comment: great man.. thanks a lot.. i'll be all over it today and let you later know how it went.

Comment: @daniel.tosaba Thinking about this, I came to another, maybe better, solution. See my update.

Comment: that's awesome man. i am right now getting on it. thank you so much for your time & effort!!

Comment: How would you add appropriate incremental value before link using filter method? 1,2,3,4,etc. Thanks!

Comment: GREAT!! Thas was so lame of me...

Comment: How did you come up with that filter hook. Is it documented??

Comment: @daniel.tosaba I look at the source code first: `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php` tells you almost everything you want to know.

Comment: Found it myself here: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/walker_nav_menu_start_el all along with the list of other potentially useful hooks. Thanks man!

Comment: Don’t rely on external sources, use the WordPress source. My plugin [All Actions List](https://gist.github.com/1979171) shows all hooks called during a single request.

Comment: Even better, I am downloading that plugin right now!!!

Comment: Hey Toscho, my knowledgeable friend, how can I var_dump $item array anywhere I want?? Thanks man

Comment: [Ask a new question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I will man in a second.. I have one which is connected with this one and it's bugging me. So I extended Walker_Nav... and placed new class in my `functions.php` but I keep getting message in my apache log: `[Mon Mar 19 13:38:44 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'new gordon_menu' not found in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 475` It looks like I am placing it in a wrong place, as I wish to call `wp_nav_menu` from my index template file.

Comment: here is the var_dump http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46135/how-to-var-dump-item-from-anywhere

Comment: figured out that i had erroneous walker call. works now!! ;)