# How to var_dump nav menu items from anywhere?

Tags: menus, variables, debug

I wanna preview all the fields that the nav menu $item array holds. Is there a function to fetch it from anywhere and place it inside var_dump?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The items are set up in [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). There is a useful filter you can use: `'wp_nav_menu_objects'`. It offers the items as `$sorted_menu_items` and the arguments of the `wp_nav_menu()` call as `$args`.

From `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php::wp_nav_menu()`:

```
$sorted_menu_items = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', $sorted_menu_items, $args );
```

So …

- hook into this filter,
- store the data somewhere,
- return the `$sorted_menu_items` unchanged and
- print the collected data after all menus are done.

In my following example I print the data on `'shutdown'` – that’s the latest hook WordPress fires.

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Collect Nav Menu Items
 * Description: Appends debug information about currently processed nav menu items to pages.
 */

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', array ( 'T5_Nav_Menu_Collector', 'collect' ), 99, 2 );

class T5_Nav_Menu_Collector
{
    /**
     * Stores the data
     * @type array
     */
    protected static $collection = array ();

    /**
     * Collect nav menu data.
     *
     * @wp-hook wp_nav_menu_objects
     * @param   array $sorted_menu_items
     * @param   array $args
     * @return  array $sorted_menu_items   Not changed.
     */
    public static function collect( $sorted_menu_items, $args )
    {
        // Since we *know* we have data, we register the print action.
        add_action( 'shutdown', array ( __CLASS__, 'print_collection' ) );

        self::$collection[] = array(
            'args'  => $args,
            'items' => $sorted_menu_items
        );
        return $sorted_menu_items;
    }

    /**
     * Dump the collected data.
     *
     * @wp-hook shutdown
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function print_collection()
    {
        $output = htmlspecialchars( print_r( self::$collection, TRUE ) );
        print "<pre><b>Nav Menu Data</b>\n\n$output</pre>";
    }
}
```

If there is no nav menu – nothing happens. But if we could collect some data, we get a nice long list at the end of a document with all item properties we can use in other filters.