# To Add Logout Button in Menu

Tags: menus, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use logout function on custom menu link?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46547/how-to-use-logout-function-on-custom-menu-link)

I want to add a logout button at very last of my nav.. I Found a function

```
// functions.php
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args)
{
  if(is_user_logged_in())
  {
    $newitems = '<li><a title="Logout" href="'. wp_logout_url('index.php') .'">Logout</a></li>';
    $newitems .= $items;
  }
  else
  {
    $newitems = '<li><a title="Login" href="'. wp_login_url('index.php') .'">Login</a></li>';
    $newitems .= $items;
  }
  return $newitems;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
```

But It adds Logout button to the very start of the nav, and i want to to be displayed on very Last. (Ideally it should be float:right, as other menu items are float:left)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorted!

Just Added

```
style="float:right;" with <li>
```