# Add "Logout" link to navigation menu

Tags: menus, login

How can I add a link to the primary navigation menu with the `class="right"` attribute?

I tried to add a static link to `example.com/wp-logout.php?action=logout` but that leads to a logout confirmation page. Is there any way to make it a log out link?

Comment: Have you seen existing questions and answers like [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46547/how-to-use-logout-function-on-custom-menu-link)?

Comment: Have you seen [`wp_loginout()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_loginout/)?

Comment: I have removed the accepted answer, because it was plagiarized from [this site](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-add-a-loginlogout-link-to-your-wordpress-menu/) without attribution.

Comment: I ended up using something similar; at least using the loginout() function. I'll post exactly what I did next time I'm in front of my computer. Thanks @toscho

Comment: You can use this free plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-logout-register-menu/ to achieve the same easily.

Comment: You can also make use of a simple plugin: [https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-or-logout-menu-item/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-or-logout-menu-item/) It does not take you to the logout confirmation page.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `wp_nav_menu_items` hook. Let's have a look at the following piece of code which shows the login/logout link on the `primary` menu location.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wti_loginout_menu_link', 10, 2 );

function wti_loginout_menu_link( $items, $args ) {
   if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
      if (is_user_logged_in()) {
         $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">'. __("Log Out") .'</a></li>';
      } else {
         $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="'. wp_login_url(get_permalink()) .'">'. __("Log In") .'</a></li>';
      }
   }
   return $items;
}
```

This is what we have implemented in the above example.

1. First added a filter for `wp_nav_menu_items` hook and attached a
   function to it.
2. After checking for `primary` theme location, we have checked whether
   user is logged in or not.
3. If logged in, we have showed the `Log Out` link otherwise the `Log In`
   link.
4. We have passed the permalink of the currently viewing page to the
   login url so that user will be redirected to the current page after
   successful login.
5. We have used the `class="right"` to the above code to meet your
   requirement.

You can find a detailed explanation on this [blog](http://www.webtechideas.com/adding-login-logout-link-to-wordpress-menu/).

Comment: @timo-s In the Twenty Seventeen (child) theme this will work only with a `top` menu location: `if ($args->theme_location == 'top')`.

Comment: location needed to be for me `primary-menu`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a custom link with http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout
It worked for me!

Comment: This presents the user with the "Are you sure you want to log out?" prompt, due to the fact that the nonce is missing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're flexible about adding a plugin to get this functionality, you could use: https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-logout-register-menu/

It simply adds a very convenient section in the menu builder. You can combine it with another plugin to restrict what menu items are shown to logged in users, which ones to logged out users, and which ones to everyone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My footer menu is a **widget**, therefore I had difficulties using the code by Chittaranjan. The following edited version works for me. I also changed the links and made them "dynamic": login leads to a page of your choice, logout will either stay on the current page, or send to home, if the current page is your (private) login page. Ideally it would check if your login page is actually private, but I don't know how to do that, sorry.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wti_loginout_menu_link', 10, 2 );

function wti_loginout_menu_link( $items, $args ) {
    //var_dump($args);
    if (($args->menu->slug == 'footer')) {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $loginlink = '/your-private-page';
            $logoutlink = get_permalink();
            if (strpos($logoutlink, $loginlink) !== false) {
                $logoutlink = '/';
            }
            $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="'. wp_logout_url($logoutlink) .'">'. __("Log Out") .'</a></li>';
        } else {
            $items .= '<li class="right"><a href="'. wp_login_url($loginlink) .'">'. __("Log In") .'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```