# Wordpress Login/Logout Single Menu Only

Tags: menus, login, logout

I've written this login/logout for my functions.php in my wordpress theme.  The problem is, it's showing a login/logout link in all menus both primary and secondary.  Is there a way to get it to appear only in secondary?

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {

    ob_start();
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';

return $items;
}
```

This is what I ended up using:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
if( $args->theme_location == 'top-menu' ) {
    ob_start();
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
}
return $items;
}
```

Comment: You need to check `$args` parameter.

Comment: Have you seen [How to use logout function on custom menu link?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46547/73)

Answer (score 1):

Change the filter hook to `wp_nav_menu_{menu-name}_items`, so it will only run on a specific menu. For example, if the menu name is "Secondary", use the hook  `wp_nav_menu_secondary_items`, or if the menu name is "Top Navigation", use `wp_nav_menu_top-navigation_items` (replace spaces in the menu name with dashes).

Your updated code, assuming the menu name is "Secondary" (the menu name, not the theme location), would be:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_secondary_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {    
    ob_start();
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();         
    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';    
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nilamber Suggessts:

```
/**
 * Add Login/Logout to Menu
 */
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        $loginoutlink = wp_loginout('index.php', false);
        $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
```

Also note, using this function, `theme_location` cannot be null.   The arg check negates the need to change the menu name in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Nilamber, You will have to check the parameters defined in $args. The following code will work but you can modify it as your ease.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );

function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
    $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
}
elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
    $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
}
return $items;
}
```

Comment: All these methods have been valid approaches, but can you explain your choice not to use `wp_loginout();`

Comment: @ECarterYoung Just a choice, any of them can be used, The main motive of answer was to clarify how to use $args in 'wp_nav_menu_items' filter.