# Add log in link to menu in Twenty Twelve

Tags: menus, login

I can't find a way to add the log in link to the new theme of WordPress, Twenty Twelve.
I did find a lot of answers on the older theme, where [they suggest to add some code in the `functions.php` file](http://wpmu.org/how-to-add-a-loginlogout-link-to-your-wordpress-menu/). However, this do not work for me.

Does anyone have a solution for this? You can see my homepage here: http://musikfest.dk/kursus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `wp_nav_menu_objects` and add the link as item, similar to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46547/how-to-use-logout-function-on-custom-menu-link).

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 't5_menu_log_link', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add a link to the nav menu.
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_nav_menu_objects
 * @param  array  $sorted_menu_items Existing nav menu items
 * @param  object $args Nav menu arguments. 'add_loginout' must be TRUE
 * @return array  Nav menu items
 */
function t5_menu_log_link( $sorted_menu_items, $args )
{
    $is_in                  = is_user_logged_in();

    $link                   = new stdClass;
    $link->title            = __( $is_in ? 'Log Out' : 'Log In' );
    $link->menu_item_parent = 0;
    $link->ID               = '';
    $link->db_id            = '';
    $link->url              = $is_in ? wp_logout_url() : wp_login_url();

    $sorted_menu_items[] = $link;

    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
```

Get it as [plugin from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/thefuxia/4412306).

Comment: I have added this as a plugin. [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/46262/25218) and add the code from here [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/46549/25218) as a function to `function.php`. I can't se any different? Do I need to do more? And if I add the code above the whole site fails.

Comment: I am using this code on a site, and it works. What error message do you get?

Comment: I get this error. I added the code to function like this [link](http://goo.gl/O0mLV). I get the error when I click update. The error: _Fatal error: Cannot redeclare t5_menu_log_link() (previously declared in /customers/d/b/b/musikfest.dk/httpd.www/kursus/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php:505) in /customers/d/b/b/musikfest.dk/httpd.www/kursus/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php on line 476_

Comment: Do not define a function twice. Do not edit TwentyTwelve, create a child theme instead.

Comment: I have copy the them and added new new theme again. I don't where I else where have define the function, so i renamed it to _t5_menu_log_link_ in both the _function_ and the _add_filter_. There are no errors but there are not link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6885/discussion-between-boje-and-toscho)

Comment: @boje See my update, I made a plugin.

Comment: I copy the code, added it as a plugin, but can't active it. Get this error _Fatal error: Cannot redeclare t6_menu_log_link() in /customers/d/b/b/musikfest.dk/httpd.www/kursus/wp-content/plugins/o_add_menu_item/o_add_men_item.php on line 24_

Comment: Remove the first declaration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6891/discussion-between-boje-and-toscho)

Comment: I needed to use the custom menu and then it works perfect.